# Correct usage of 'one'

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Consider the statements:

'There was one girl, XYZ, ..'

'There was one mountain, XYZ, ..'

Are the sentences correct?

Comment: Only use ***one*** in contexts where you've already referred to *multiple* girls/mountains/etc. (or the context strongly implies the fact that there are many of them). Note that in the spoken form, ***one*** would always have relatively high stress in such usages.

Answer (score 4):

1. *There was a girl, Patricia, who was very tall.*

   This ***introduces*** the girl to us. It could be the beginning of a narrative.
2. *I met a group of girls. There was one girl, Patricia, who was very tall.*

   In this case we have singled out just ***one*** of the girls from a previously mentioned group.

Comment: I deleted my answer which misunderstood the question as referring to punctuation. As this answer suggests, the difference between using *one* or *a* is that a doesn't suggest that the girl is part of a larger set of girls.

Comment: But you would say *There was a group of people among which was a girl called Patricia*.

Comment: @GetzelR the indefinite article is etymologically derived from the number one.  If you think about it for a while you'll see that they are interchangeable in most contexts, with minimal change in meaning.  In many languages, they continue to be the same (German, French, Italian, Spanish, arguably Dutch, for example).

Comment: But the change in meaning identified here is still valid. Explicitly using "one" implies there are others to consider, whereas using *a* does not.